# How to run Jupyter Notebook code in django project

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, nltk

My friend and I are collaborating to make a website which has recommendation function. I have completed this function in Jupyter Notebook (because it supports so many packages) and my friend is making the website with html,css and js. We want to combine by using Django framework, but I concerns whether Django supports those packages that I used or not? and if It doesn't, please recommend me some ways to do it.

Comment: in django environment you need to install those packages, it will work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way I want to ask you that I used those packages and  I wrote some function for my purpose. I have two concerns here.                          
1. I am not sure the way to install those packages in Django environment. Do you have some guides for me?
2. Assume that I installed them successfully, Can I use them to write my function in View layer as the way I write in Jupyter Notebook? 
Looking forward your help. Thanks